# Run SQL inline queries on Mediawiki

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I would like to be able to run SQL queries in pages of a Mediawiki (inline queries). I am not even sure if this is possible or if we can do it only through SSH. I find information provided by MediaWiki pretty confusing for a new user.

As far as i am concerned, the SQL queries are wrapped for security reasons, so syntax will not be SQL exactly.

The questions would be:
Can we make inline SQL (or wrapped SQL) queries in Mediawiki pages? If yes, how? If not, is there a 'similar' alternative for it? (For example, creating a function with the query in it an accessing it). Please, provide examples if possible and take in account i am not familiar with Mediawiki data structure.
Let´s assume, for example, that i want to know all pages created by a users named 'user1' and 'user2'.

Also, if there is an extension which helps with this it would be worth mentioning.

I am using wampserver3.0.6_x64, apache2.4.23, mysql5.7.14 and php5.6.25.

Comment: [SQL2Wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SQL2Wiki) does raw queries but as you say it's super insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, i tested 2 extensions which in conjuction can work very well for this task:

[Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo)
And [Page forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms)

Cargo allows you creating SQL tables which work independently from other MW content (meaning that you will have to introduce info in these tables using a wrapped SQL syntax, recommendedly through forms which call templates with the query).